# How does Basic Authentication works specific directory in Laravel5.1?

Tags: laravel-5.1, basic-authentication

I want to set Basic Authentication in specific views directory.

I set a htaccess file and htpasswd file in views directory, but it dosen't work.

resources--views--admin  ←set them here!

I know there is a htaccess file in public directory.
Should i use it to set Basic Authentication works specific directory?

Please tell me how to work Basic Authentication at specific directory in Laravel5.1.

Answer (score 0):

The basic Laravel Authentication is set up by running a php artisan commend:

```
php artisan auth:make
```

This will then make your view for the login page and a `HomeController`. and update your `routes.php` file under the middleware `web`

Once you have done that you will just need to make a form on the login page which looks like this. Which you can find under `../resources/views/auth/login.blade.php`

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
                    {!! csrf_field() !!}

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                <i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-in"></i>Login
                            </button>

                            <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">Forgot Your Password?</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

And you will be given a register page which will look like this. Which can be found under `../resources/views/auth/resgister.blade.php`

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/register') }}">
                    {!! csrf_field() !!}

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">

                            @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">

                            @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                <i class="fa fa-btn fa-user"></i>Register
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

With these you can set up your Authentication with in laravel. Just make sure any routes that are using your Auth method are in the web middleware group

If you are wanting an admin pages and you have auth then you can set up a middleware so it checks they are admin before they can even hit the route